# YouTube Kids vs. Regular YouTube with Restricted Mode?

Tags: youtube

I have two young daughters (age 11 and 8) who like to browse videos on YouTube. But I want to prevent them from viewing any age-inappropriate content.

One daughter has an iPad on which we installed the [YouTube Kids](https://kids.youtube.com/) app. It works great. She can only watch videos that have been curated by YouTube staff.

The other daughter has a Chromebook. She accesses YouTube through the Chrome browser. I have set Restricted-Mode: On. I believed that by doing so she would be restricted to watching only the same videos that can by found in the YouTube kids app.

But that's not the case. The Chromebook (even with Restricted Mode) allows my daughter to access videos that are not available via YouTube Kids.

If I want my kids to ONLY watch videos found on YouTube Kids, must I get them an Android or iPad device so they can use the app?

Here is a video available via Chromebook with Restricted Mode = On, but not available on YouTube Kids: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Eu7VPGWSaow

Answer (score 2):

Restricted mode indeed is less restrictive than YTKids.

> If I want my kids to ONLY watch videos found on YouTube Kids, must I get them an Android or iPad device so they can use the app?

[Or a smartTV.](https://support.google.com/youtubekids/topic/7317610?hl=en-GB&ref_topic=6130504) But yes, you won't be able to let your kid use a PC-like device if you don't think restricted mode is filtering enough.

*Aside: Even if there was YTKids-level filtering on desktop, you still wouldn't want to let a kid watch YouTube unsupervised. The bad content is always just one tab away.*